# Forward declaration in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

Consider the following scenario:

"A.cpp":

```cpp
void fun() { std::cout << "fun() global\n"; }
```

"B.cpp":

```cpp
namespace N
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "f() in N\n";
        
        void fun(); // forward declaration
        fun();
    }
}
```

When `N::f();` is called from some other file (say "C.cpp"), the compiler throws an "undefined symbol" error for `fun()`.

How to fix this without making any changes to "A.cpp"?

Comment: There's nothing in this question to indicate that the definition in `A.cpp` is in the namespace `N`, as opposed to the global namespace.

Comment: do you have headers? How do you compile and link the files?

Comment: Why did you put `void fun();` in scope of a function, which is in scope of namespace `N`? Move this outside! Now you have declared a `void N::fun();` https://godbolt.org/z/z6Y4zK7zh

Comment: If you (really) cannot move the declaration in B.cpp, you still can move the definition in A.cpp: `namespace N { void fun() { std::cout << "fun() global\n"; } }`. https://godbolt.org/z/5nbaKPcWf

Comment: @NathanPierson you are correct. It is global in the unit A.cpp

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have a B.h but no A.h

Comment: @MarekR can't change A.cpp

Comment: If you cannot change A.cpp, @MarekR already demonstrated a solution... https://godbolt.org/z/zqjfznsrb

Comment: And if you cannot change A.cpp nor B.cpp, you have to introduce a trampoline so that `N::fun()` calls `::fun()` (or vice versa)... :-)

Comment: @CinCout I didn't recommend you to change `A.cpp` but `B.cpp`.

Comment: @MarekR my bad. Guess I should call it a day!

Comment: If you don't have any header file that declares `f` then it is either not meant to be called by you, or badly designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix this without making any changes to "A.cpp"?

You need to forward declare `fun` in *global namespace* instead of inside namespace `N`. This can be done by moving the declaration `void fun();` to outside `N` as shown below:

**B.cpp**

```
void fun(); //this is a forward declaration in global namespace 
namespace N
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "f() in N\n";
        
        //no declaration needed here
        fun();
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Ypj_nqWP9)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using `::` to forward declare?

Comment: @CinCout No because `::` cannot be used in a forward declaration. I mean if you're thinking about writing `void ::f();` for the forward declaration inside namespace `N` then that is not allowed.